# Applying query slop(qs) to string field in solr

Tags: solr

My default solr config looks like:

```
<str name="qf">
   id^1.0 field1^100 field2^60 field3^10
</str>
<str name="qs">2</str>
```

where id and field2 are string types and others are custom types.
I am using the extended disjunction max query parser.

On running a query with `debugQuery=true`

Query: "IO exceptions"(with quotes)
This is the parsedQuery:

```
(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((id:IO exceptions | field1:"io except"~2^100.0 field2:IO exceptions^60.0 | field3:"io except"~2^10.0)) ())/no_coord
```

Does anyone know the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String fields are for exact matches. There is no slop available for a StrField. If you want to apply a slop, use a TextField with a Whitespace tokenizers or something similar.

Your parsedQuery also shows that the StrFields only matches exactly, while the other fields are stemmed before queried.